# Community shows blank page when it's deactivated

Tags: community, force.com-sites, community-builder, partner-communities

My community is showing a blank page instead of down for maintainence page when it's been deactivated .I have set the InMaintainence page(the standard page not the custom) in **Inactive Site Home Page**  on Site detail page .I haven't been able to find any solution for the same.Is there any setting that I have been missing.Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this in one of the known issues of Salesforce.The issue is that whenever a user deactivates a Customer Service (Napili) Community, it  results in a blank page being displayed when accessed by the guest user.Here is th Link:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAUtQAO

Comment: please remember to mark your answer as accepted to move it out of the unanswered question queue.

Comment: @DaveHumm I have accepted the answer.Thanks for pointing out.